# When signing with server public key, how do I prove server key is trustworthy?

Tags: rsa, public-key, authentication

I have a server-side app in a Docker container that communicates with my desktop client app.

I am struggling with how to ensure that the `response` from the server is trustworthy. I am fairly new to working with RSA key pairs and establishing client-server trustworthy communication.

The most common answer I have seen is to sign the `response` with the `private key` that was used to generate the server's HTTPS certificate.  AFAIK this certificate is normally generated by a trusted Certificate Authority (CA), but it could be produced by LetsEncrypt. My understanding is that LetsEncrypt certificates are considered self-signed, and not as trusted as CA-generated certificates.  Either way, this is where the 'trust' in the server's response supposedly comes from.

This leads me to the following problems:

1. How does the client retrieve the server's CA-issued certificate, if the certificate is hidden in some `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` folder?  This is where the certificate is located on my host.
2. How does the server-side app access the private key that produced that certificate, if the private key is hidden in some `/etc/pki/tls/private/` folder that requires root access?  This is where the private key is located on my host.
3. How can I set up my docker container to have a CA-issued certificate for development purposes prior to deploying the app to my host, which already has a CA-issued certificate.

This is what I've implemented, since I haven't solved 1, 2 or 3:

```
client sends initial request to server.
server generates and stores RSA key pair.
server sends public key to client as the response.
client stores public key for use later.
```

Now that the client has the server's public key, every request/response pair can follow this algorithm:

```
client sends new request to server.
server creates some response.
server generates a hash of this response.
server encrypts this hash with the RSA private key.
server sends the response, and encrypted hash to the client.

client receives server's response and encrypted hash.
client hashes the response with same algorithm the server used.
client decrypts the encrypted hash using the public key it received earlier.
client compares the decrypted hash with the hash the client computed. 

if the hashes match, the response from the server is trustworthy.
```

This algorithm works just fine with my Docker container running locally on my computer, where trust in the public key from the server is not mandatory.

I would like to sign the responses with the CA-issued private key, instead of the RSA private key generated when the client's first request is received.
When I deploy this docker app to my host, I'm hoping this is how I'll be able to prove that responses from the server are trustworthy.

I'm struggling to understand how the client gets the CA-issued certificate (public key), and how the server can access the CA-issued private key.

The desktop client app is written in C++ (JUCE), the server-side app is written in PHP.

Comment: Fun fact: the certificate of _this very website_ is issued by Let's Encrypt. It's trusted on basically everything. I think LE can't issue extended validation certs, but most sites don't bother with those anyhow.

Comment: Let's Encrypt **is a "trusted Certificate Authority (CA)"**. Years ago they were supported by other CAs by having their roots cross-signed by these CAs, but they have their own indipendent root CAs trusted in all major systems for a while now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that LetsEncrypt certificates are considered self-signed, and not as trusted as CA-generated certificates.

No. The CA certificate of Let's Encrypt is issued and signed by CA "ISRG X1", Internet Security Research Group. On Linux systems it is usually preinstalled and can be found in the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem`.

When client validates TLS certificate, it requests the whole certificate chain from your server. The certificate of your server is signed by Let's Encrypt. The certificate of Let's Encrypt is signed by ISRG X1. The latter is trusted because it is preinstalled in your system.

> How can I set up my docker container to have a CA-issued certificate for development purposes prior to deploying the app to my host, which already has a CA-issued certificate.

Normally separate application instances don't get access to the TLS private key. Instead, there is a web server that acts as a reverse proxy. It is responsible for TLS connection. In particular, it has the whole certificate chain and access to the private key. It decrypts TLS request received from the client and forwards it to the corresponding application. Since you already have an application that uses TLS, you may want to add the new application behind the same reverse proxy. It does not need access to certificate because it will receive traffic from the reverse proxy, not from the client directly.

> how the client gets the CA-issued certificate (public key)

As described above, client requests the certificate chain from the server when it establishes TLS connection. This chain includes the CA certificate of Let's Encrypt tha is issued and signed by ISRG X1, whose certificate is preinstalled on the client and thus is trusted.

> how the server can access the CA-issued private key

Private key is not issued. When you request a certificate, you generate a key pair. You keep private key secret. When you request certificate from CA, you send to CA only your public key, it is a part of CSR. When you generate a key pair, you provide the private key to your server that is responsible for TLS, e.g. to your reverse proxy. The application behind this web server or reverse proxy does not need access to the private key.

[Here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) are references to different tools that can help to automate requesting TLS certificates from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Not entirely sure that the answer to the second question couldn't be expanded with other options (it doesn't claim to be the only solution though, and I think that this is the most configuration that is often deployed). Hopefully there will be some other answers that can expand on it.

Comment: Note that reverse proxies can forward the security information for the specific connection towards the applications. This is especially important if you have some kind of access control that is dependent on client authentication. See e.g. [Java / Tomcat configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/ajp.html) as an example for this kind of setup; you may want to look into that for your particular runtime.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Of course, decrypting TLS and forwarding requests to different applications is only one of possible scenarios. Another could be, as you mentioned, a server like Tomcat that does everything: Decrypts TLS and processes requests directly, by passing requests to Java applications deployed on this Tomcat server.

Comment: The AJP connector in the link uses the Apache HTTP server (native C) with Tomcat (Java). However, it forwards the security details so that the server or servlet application can still use them for e.g. access control. So it uses Apache HTTP as proxy / TLS endpoint and possibly for some caching / static content.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: There are also other similar setups, e.g. IBM HTTPD Server (or Apache HTTP Server or MS IIS) + IBM WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: @mentallurg thank you so much for the detailed explanation. 
Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong. You are saying that I don't even need to provide signatures in responses to the client because the TLS layer is doing that already for me because I'm using HTTPS.  The response my client app receives is **after** the https/TLS/OS layers of communication has finished and the encrypted packets sent from the server have been decrypted by the TLS/OS layer. Is that correct?  i.e. the client can trust ANY message from the server because TLS/https was used?

Comment: @MatkatMusic: *"the client can trust ANY message from the server because TLS/https was used"* - Correct. If you are developing an application, usually you don't implement "low level" layers like TLS or HTTP, but use some library instead. You specify a URL that you want to send a request to. It contains "https:" scheme. Based on this instruction, the library establishes a TLS connection...

Comment: ... And if you received a response in your client code, this means a lot: A) The connection was established to the server you wanted to and not to some other server; B) The traffic was encrypted and nobody can decrypt request and response even if they recorded the whole traffic between client and server; C) The data were not modified on their way between client and server.

Comment: Awesome!!  Now I just to figure out how to set up Docker to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.  Thank you so so much for clarifying all of this!  I was going nuts implementing RSA Key exchange and ChaCha key exchange on top of this existing TLS layer, to send encrypted messages on top of this already-encrypted TLS layer!!!

Comment: Generally you would only do something like that if you require that additional layer, e.g. when you want to store the data encrypted on the server. In that case TLS is not much use as the encryption will be stripped off by the transport layer. So it is not common to use client side encryption for that (I've done it, but the identity and banking communities are very concerned about that kind of thing, you don't want to store data unencrypted).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes My use case is for an authorization system that stores app data on the client's side.  the server encrypts generic data that every app installation receives using a unique key pair generated for each client upon successful authorization.  regarding this: "When you want to store the data encrypted on the server".  Are you referring to the client storing the data locally (that the server sent), or storing data remotely (that the client sent to the server)?

Comment: @MatkatMusic: It doesn't matter where you store the data to be encrypted. I am saying that generating key pair separately and encrypting the private key with HSM is *more simple*